# isc-dhcp issuing wrong ip for subnet

Tags: linux, dhcp, vlan, subnet

i've configured a range of IP pools to a new server i've configured. 
the client contacts the correct router IP for the assigned subnet, but receives an IP completely out of scope for the subnet.
the switchport is access and untagged to 157

```
shared-network NEW-DHCP {
        option domain-name-servers 10.194.blah.blah , 10.194.blah.blah;
        authoritative;
        allow client-updates;
       allow unknown-clients;
        ddns-updates off;

 VLAN 75 - TESTING VLAN
        subnet 10.194.75.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
               option routers 10.194.75.1;
                range 10.194.75.10 10.194.75.250;
                }
 VLAN 157 - USERS 157
        subnet 10.194.142.128 netmask 255.255.255.128 {
                option routers 10.194.142.129;
                range 10.194.142.138 10.194.142.250;
                }

 Feb 24 10:38:00 dhcp01 dhcpd[9219]: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:08:5d:xx:xx:xx via 10.194.142.130
 Feb 24 10:38:01 dhcp01 dhcpd[9219]: DHCPOFFER on 10.194.75.12 to 00:08:5d:xx:xx:xx via 10.194.142.130
 Feb 24 10:38:01 dhcp01 dhcpd[9219]: DHCPREQUEST for 10.194.75.12 (10.194.yy.yy) from     00:08:5d:xx:xx:xx via >10.194.142.130
 Feb 24 10:38:01 dhcp01 dhcpd[9219]: DHCPACK on 10.194.75.12 to 00:08:5d:xx:xx:xx via 10.194.142.130
```

Comment: What does the `ifconfig` or `ip a` look like on the DHCP server?

Comment: the server only has one IP, i've not configured it with virtual interfaces. The IP was not in either VLAN 75 or 157
i managed to resolve this issue by removing the shared-network declaration and used stand alone subnets.